# Reference Request for Metric Spaces

Tags: real-analysis

I am studying metric spaces for first time myself.

I have read the theory.
I want to try problems. I tried Topology of Metric Spaces by S. Kumaresan. But the solution is not available in detail.

I want to lots of problems but the issues is I am unable to verify my solutions and I am not interested in using internet to verify each solution. This is because I want to stay away from distraction as much as possible.

I want someone to suggest me books on Metric Spaces which has Problems and solutions in detail. so that I can get confident with these topics.

Comment: metric spaces are used all the time in analysis books, so if you read some analysis book you will use it all the time. You can put your solutions here and we can see if they are correct or not.

Comment: Micheal O Searcoid, *Metric Spaces* (Springer 2007) is inexpensive, it looks pretty comprehensive (I haven't read it), it has 244 exercises, and it provides solutions for 108 of them.

Comment: @Masacroso Sir, I would like to do a self study and because I cannot put each and every question here because of time restrictions, I would prefer using a good reference. Time Restriction is that I have to complete metric spaces for Entrance Exams. However I will put good questions here. I need a good solutions so I can verify each of my solution after attempting. I am not intended to copy paste everything.