# Book recommendation for Metric Spaces

Tags: reference-request, metric-spaces, book-recommendation

I'm currently studying Undergraduate level - III, and I have a course of Elementary Metric Spaces, basically for a starter level. Now, for better concepts, I need a good book. One of my friends in my class suggested the book of Topology by J. Munkres, but there is just a small part of it. Please suggest me some books completely dealing with metric spaces.

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Principles of Mathematical Analysis by Rudin (aka ‘baby Rudin’) is fairly standard.

Comment: although it's only a small part of it, Munkres does do a good job of presenting the important topological properties of metric spaces, as well as exploring the conditions necessary for a topological space to be able to be a metric space.

Comment: Understanding analysis by Stephen Abbott is a good book. Not sure how much it has on metric spaces, but if it does, then I’d probably recommend it.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of [Reference Request for Metric Spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2910633)?

Comment: No duplicate as that question has no answers.

Comment: Also see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/89642/a-good-book-for-metric-spaces?rq=1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Topology of Metric Spaces, Alpha Science International Ltd. (2005)* by S. Kumaresan gives a very streamlined development of a course in metric space topology emphasising only the most useful concepts and geometric ideas. To encourage geometric thinking, the book boasts of having
a large number of examples to develop our intuition and draw conclusions and generate ideas for proofs. There are a lot of exercises aiding in grasping the material to the core.

*Metric Spaces, Springer (2000)* by Satish Shirali and Harikrishnan. L. Vasudeva provides a leisurely approach to the theory of metric spaces. To ensure
that the ideas take root gradually but firmly, a large number of examples and
counterexamples follow each definition. Also included are several worked examples
and exercises. Applications of the theory are spread out over the entire book.

*Metric Spaces, Springer (2007)* by Micheál O'Searcoid is a book from Springer Undergraduate Mathematics Series, provides a fairly thorough introduction to metric spaces. It has a lot of examples and problems related to almost all the basic concepts. Interested ones can also check their answers with the solution manual.

---

Apt to it's name, [*Notes on Metric Spaces*](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://scholar.princeton.edu/sites/default/files/jxandri/files/notes_on_metric_spaces_0.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjVucu2qY7gAhUHXSsKHe8CB7AQFjAAegQIARAB&usg=AOvVaw1Tpo17L_VGabrAB94yP8Fz) offered by Juan Pablo Xandari is very helpful with simpler proofs and helpful for quick revisions.

Of course Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* is widely regarded as a standard resource for analysis, though it actually doesn't deal with compactness or connectedness.

Comment: While Rudin may be standard, I believe it isn't a good book on metric spaces. It is pretty basic, as it doesn't prove things like compact = complete + totally bounded = every sequence has convergent subsequence or does not talk about path connectedness etc.

Comment: But as an analysis book, it is great, but not as a topology book on metric spaces. It can serve merely as an introduction.

Comment: @Math_QED I agree. As you said, it just provides introduction to the real analysis and doesn't actually deal with metric spaces.

Answer (score 0):

An Introduction to Metric Spaces by Dhananjay Gopal, Aniruddha Deshmukh, Abhay S. Ranadive, Shubham Yadav is a nice book to read about Metric Spaces. The chapters in the book are arranged in a logically linear fashion.

Also, you can look at Metric Spaces by Satish Shirali, Harkrishan L. Vasudeva.